# Bootstrap 3 affix triggering on scrolling on div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page using Bootstrap 3 and Snap.js library (https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/).

I need to have a navbar with affix.

Unfortunately, affix seems to work using `window.scroll` element, that is not working in this case (i'm wondering why, if I log `window.pageYOffset` every second it remains fixed to zero and it never fires `window.onscroll` trigger.).

Is there any way to bind Affix to the scrolling of an inner element?

(similar issue: [Bootstrap Affix not working inside an Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481410/bootstrap-affix-not-working-inside-an-iframe))

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, it's just written in the documentation:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14932

In my case:

```
<div id="toolbarContainer" data-spy="affix" data-target=".snap-content" data-offset-top="100">
   [...]
</div>
```